# How to get groovy compiler time (phase) source code

Tags: groovy

Groovy console allows me to get the Groovy AST browser. In this, I can select the compiler "end of phase" option. Then, I can see the source and bytecode of the source code. My goal is to automate this process based on compiler phases and to get the "source" section as illustrated in the console output figure below. More particularly, I don't want to use the Groovy console every time. Is there a way to do this?

For example, the code below is shown in source section of the AST browser, starting with `public class Dog extends...`

```
class Dog {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        println "hello"
    }
}
class Cat {
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"My goal is to automate this process..." What process?  Unless you rewrite the "Groovy AST Browser" yourself, I think you have to use the Groovy Console to get to it.  However, if what you want to do is automate access to the AST Tree so you can, for example, intercept method calls or inject methods, then there is a way to do that.  Check out http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html section 2 - compile time meta-programming

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be precise, the code shown in Groovy console is the one that I would like to get without using the Groovy console.

Comment: Maybe looking into the source code of the actual Groovy AST Browser, I'm sure it's written in Groovy, will answer your questions.  You might also check the source code of the "Groovy AST Browser on the Web" at https://github.com/roshandawrani/groovyastbrowser for answers.